# Convert a file path to a URL in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What the simplest way to convert a file path to a absolute url. Example:

### file:

```
C:\myapp\src\SqlExpress\wwwroot\data\images\test.jpg
```

url:

```
http://localhost/data/images/test.jpg
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
    static string Convert(string path)
    {
        return path.Replace(@"C:\myapp\src\SqlExpress\wwwroot", @"http://localhost").Replace('\\', '/');
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string url = Convert(@"C:\myapp\src\SqlExpress\wwwroot\data\images\test.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: @ScopeCreep `Server.MapPath()` is NOT in .Net Core.

Comment: This answer will work, however, just for this situation.  What if there is a port number?  What happens when you push to QA or production and you are no longer on localhost?

Answer (score 9):

This is what I did. I never could find a way to easily find the wwwroot path outside a controller. So I used a static variable in Startup class, which is accessible throughout the application.

```
public class Startup
{
    public static string wwwRootFolder = string.Empty;

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        Startup.wwwRootFolder = env.WebRootPath;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then in wherever I want..

```
public static string GetUrlFromAbsolutePath(string absolutePath)
{
    return absolutePath.Replace(Startup.wwwRootFolder, "").Replace(@"\", "/");
}
```

Comment: This should have been marked as the accepted answer. Just tried this and works perfectly for me. The problem with the accepted answer is that it is for a hardcoded path.

Comment: You can access the **WebRootFolder** from the `IHostingEnvironment` by injecting it in the controller and accessing via `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath`

Comment: How to access it from outside a controller? That was my point.

Comment: @SoundarRajan with depedency injection you can inject it in any class. not specific to controller. service class, repository so on...